# How to fix ajax runs when i try to select option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My form contains two select elements. Submission should occur via AJAX only when the *onclick* event handler bound to `button#assignrole` is triggered.

But currently, the AJAX call is fired as soon as I select an option from the "User" dropdown:

[image: gif-scenario]

I have tried to disable all other scripts in my footer, header etc and only kept jQuery v3.4.1

```php
<!-- Assign Role To User -->
<div class="modal fade" id="assignrole" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Assign Role To User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectuser">Select User</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="selectuser">
              <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
              <option value="<?= $user['id'] ?>">
                <?= $user['username'] ?>
              </option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectrole">Select Role</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="selectrole" data-live-search="false">
              <?php foreach ($roles as $role): ?>
              <option value="<?= $role['id'] ?>">
                <?= $role['role_name'] ?>
              </option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" id="assignrole" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var base_url = "http://127.0.0.1/ci3/";

  $("#assignrole").on('click', function() {
    var user_id = $('#selectuser option:selected').attr('value');
    var role_id = $('#selectrole option:selected').attr('value');

    $.ajax({
      url: base_url + "backend/assign_role",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "role_id": role_id
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.status == 1) {
          alert("Data Send Success");
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("maybe your login session timed out, try to login again!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

no errors show up

Comment: You have a on change handler assigned to #selectuser (and probably the #selectrole too). search for .change() or .on('change' in your code.

Comment: i have searched it there's no .on('change') :(

Comment: try changing the id of your dropdown. It could be on click also (on change is a better option)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Boom Boom. It's probable that the `click` event listener sends a request every time you *click* on the select. But we'll know that for sure if you add the HTML containing the `#assignrole` element.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier but i set the click event on button not dropdown

Comment: Show us more relevant HTML so we can help you out.

Comment: @charlietfl now its full html, please check

Comment: `#assignrole` is the whole modal, so clicking anywhere in it will run that ajax

Comment: OK...looks like you repeated the id and it is on modal **and** button. Since ID's must be unique the first one found is the modal itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have duplicate ID's.

Here:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="assignrole" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

And here:

```
<button type="submit" id="assignrole" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

So that means that when you add the `click` event it will be set on the first hit of that ID. Which in your case is the `modal` element.

```
$("#assignrole") // <div class="modal fade" id="assignrole" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Changing the ID's of one of the two elements will fix the click issue.

Comment: thanks it worked but now its refresh page after alert data success, and i have not set any refresh or redirect thing

Comment: @BoomBoom You need to prevent the default form submit process

Comment: Yup, thats because when you are *clicking* the button you are also *submitting* the form that button is in. I suggest that instead of using the `click` event  on the `button` that you use the `submit` event on the `form` element. And don't forget `event.preventDefault()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you selector ("#assignrole") is not appropriate.
you have 2 html element with same ids:

```
<button type="submit" id="assignrole" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="assignrole" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"></div>
```

remove the modal id.

Comment: After formatting the code with the html being present this is correct. There are multiple IDs and since most* html elements fire the `click` event. The select `click` event was bubbling up to the `#assignedrole` element which jQuery was binding to. While IDs may appear unique from the HTML point of view CSS and jQuery selectors will bind to all instances.

Comment: @Itanex That's not true. When you use an id selector it will *always* be the first one. That is not a jQuery issue...it is a querySelector issue since browser only returns first one

Comment: Yes `getElementById` and `querySelector` do only return 1 because that is how those APIs work. `querySelectorAll` will return all of them by design. CSS with style ALL elements that qualify under `#myId`. From what it appears jQuery has changed since I last looked at its selector handling, `$('#myid')` does appear to return only one element now as it detects the '#' and uses `getElementById`.